# how to get individual-clinic-month that are excluded from SQL query

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, logic

I have the following dataset:

```
individual  |  clinic_1   | clinic_2    | month      | address_recorded | address_code
1           |  A          | B           | 01-01-2016 | 01-02-1999       | C01
1           |  A          | A           | 01-01-2016 | 01-02-2003       | C02
1           |  A          | A           | 01-01-2016 | 01-02-2001       | C06
1           |  A          | X           | 01-01-2016 | 01-02-2000       | C03
2           |  C          | B           | 01-04-2016 | 01-02-1999       | D04
2           |  C          | A           | 01-04-2016 | 01-02-2001       | D05
2           |  C          | X           | 01-04-2016 | 01-02-2000       | D06
```

I would like to get:

```
individual  |  clinic_1   | month      | address_code
1           |  A          | 01-01-2016 | C02
2           |  C          | 01-04-2016 | D05
```

Criteria:

- For unique set of individual-clinic_1-month with clinic_1 = clinic_2, select the most
  recent date in which address was recorded within clinic_1
- For unique set of individual-clinic_1-month with NO instances where clinic_1 = clinic_2,
  select the most recent date in which address was recorded across
  clinics

I thought about doing:

```
with cte_1
as
(
select * from table
where clinic_1 = clinic_2
)
,cte_2
as
(
select row_number () over (Partition by clinic_1, individual, month order by clinic_1, individual, month, address_recorded desc) as number, *
from cte_1
)
select individual, clinic_1, month, address_code from cte_2 where number = 1
```

But I don't know how to get those individual-clinic_1-month for which there are no instances where clinic_1=clinic_2, any ideas?

Comment: For `address_code = C03 or D05` the `address_recorded` is the same, why `D05` is selected not `C03`?

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed and sorry my mistake - I have updated my initial table under "address_recorded" for 2nd, 3rd and 4th row. I would like to select for each unique set of individual-clinic_1-month, the code that was most recently recorded, so there will be no competition between D and C codes, because these are different individuals on different clinic_1 and times. Does it make sense?

Comment: So you want to select the most recent `address_recorded` where `clinic_1=clinic_2` together with most recent `address_recorded` where `clinic_1<>clinic_2` , is that the case?

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed. Yes, but for example, in 1st and 4th row clinic_1<>clinic_2, but because for that individual-clinic_1-month we have instances where clinic_1=clinic_2 (2nd and 3th row) I do not want to include those observations. I want to end up with 2nd table, 1 row per individual-clinic_1-month, does that make sense?

Comment: Check this fiddle and update me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17353a1a024f192825768f3b0d176515

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed - this solution does not work for me because of the following "AND [clinic_1] NOT IN (SELECT cte.[clinic_1] from cte)" - it has to be individual-clinic_1-month, because the clinic_1 in my real dataset appears again for the same or different individual in other months. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a while, I got it now and I will post an answer hoping that it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `Union` two select queries; one to select all records where `clinic_1=clinic_2` and another one to select all records where `clinic_1<>clinic_2`
and `clinic_1` not in the results set of the first query.

Both queries are grouped by `[individual],[clinic_1], [clinic_2], [mnth]` to find all of the required data rows for each `[clinic_1] - [mnth]` entry. Noting that for the 2nd query `[clinic_2]` is selected as `''`.

Check the following:

```
with cte as
(SELECT  [individual] ,[clinic_1],[clinic_2],[mnth],max([address_recorded]) as m
  FROM [MyData] where [clinic_1]=[clinic_2]
  group by [individual],[clinic_1],[clinic_2] ,[mnth] 
),
cte2 as
(SELECT  [MyData].[individual] ,[MyData].[clinic_1],'' as [clinic_2],[MyData].[mnth],max([MyData].[address_recorded]) as m
  FROM [MyData] 
  Left Join cte on cte.individual=MyData.individual
  and cte.mnth=MyData.mnth
  where [MyData].[clinic_1]<>[MyData].[clinic_2] and cte.individual IS NULL
  group by [MyData].[individual],[MyData].[clinic_1], [MyData].[mnth] 
),
D as
(SELECT * FROM cte
UNION
SELECT * FROM cte2)
, 
LastQr as(
select [MyData].individual, [MyData].clinic_1,[MyData].mnth,[MyData].address_code,
row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [MyData].individual, [MyData].clinic_1,[MyData].mnth ORDER BY [MyData].individual, [MyData].clinic_1,[MyData].mnth)
as rn from D
INNER JOIN [MyData]
ON D.individual=MyData.individual and D.clinic_1=MyData.clinic_1 and D.mnth=MyData.mnth and D.m=MyData.address_recorded
and (D.clinic_2=MyData.clinic_2 or D.clinic_2='')
)

select * from LastQr where rn=1
```

See the results from [dbfiddle.uk.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=933ea807f081264d7574c72e099faa46)

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, I think the issue remains. I included "(3,'A','X','01-05-2016','01-02-2000','D06')" as 8th row in MyData values in dbfiddle and can see that the query is not working as it should because individual 3 is also part of clinic_1 A, yet is not showing up in the results

Comment: I think the problem is "[clinic_1] not in (select cte.[clinic_1] FROM cte where mnth=cte.mnth and cte.[clinic_1]=[clinic_1])"

Comment: If I include "(1,'A','B','01-02-2016','01-02-2000','R06');" as another row in MyData values , it should appear as result because it is same individual 1 same clinic_1 A but different month "01-02-2016". Currently, it does not appear in results using your query

Comment: Ok, give me a couple of minutes I will try to fix that.

Comment: Yes, the problem was with the sub query, I replaced it with `LEFT JOIN`, kindly, check it

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed, "(3,'A','X','01-05-2016','01-02-2000','D06')" is there now, that's great, But "(1,'A','B','01-02-2016','01-02-2000','R06')" still does not show up

Comment: Sorry, just found out that if you include in MyData the following (4,'C','A','01-03-2016','01-02-2000','R06'),
(4,'C','C','01-03-2016','01-02-2000','R060'); we should only see the 2nd, but both show up

Comment: (4,'C','A','01-03-2016','01-02-2000','R06'), (4,'C','C','01-03-2016','01-02-2000','R060') both of rows are showing up because of the last `inner join`, since both of them have the same `address_recorded` date. Is ok to add extra column to the data table to uniquely identify the row. i.e. auto id?

Comment: I see, thanks @Ahmed I think so, and what would that mean? Will it pick the first row amongst those with same address_recorded?

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed - (4,'C','C','01-03-2016','01-02-2000','R06'), 
(4,'C','C','01-03-2016','01-02-2000','R060') still show as 2 rows instead of 1, is there a way to pick the first row whenever address_record is the same for both?

Comment: Updated to select first row whenever `address_record` is the same for both.

Comment: You are always welcome :)